# Is there a better way to cycle between a list of inputs?

Tags: jquery

Given the following HTML and JS code, is there a more elegant way to cycle between the "peso" inputs? It's working right now but I'm feeling I over complicated myself.

Every time `setWeight()` is called the program should set the value on the current "peso" input, jump to the next and, if is the last one, start over.

```
<table id="mlotes">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td><input type="number" class="lote"></td>
       <td><input type="text" class="peso" readonly></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>2</td>
       <td><input type="number" class="lote"></td>
       <td><input type="text" class="peso" readonly></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td><input type="number" class="lote"></td>
       <td><input type="text" class="peso" readonly></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

```
    function setWeight(weight){
      var tbl = $('#mlotes > tbody');
      var ae = $(document.activeElement);
    
      if (ae.hasClass('peso')) {
        ae.data('peso', weight).val(weight.formatMoney(2));
    
        if (ae.closest('tr').next('tr').index() != -1){ 
          ae.closest('tr').next('tr').find('.peso').focus();
        }else{
          tbl.find('tr:first').find('.peso').focus();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: When is `setWeight()` called, and what is an example value of `weight`? We need a working example in order to understand how the logic is structured and to see how it can be improved.

Comment: `setWeight()` is called when a message comes from a web socket connection, the whole idea is to show the last 3 weights.